# flutter app apk installed file,firebase_auth/unknown

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

apk file sign in or register will throw this error: [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.j:an internal error has occurred.[json conversion failed! ] failed to parse error for string[   Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1  ...]
....
web app, chrome view works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5IZp.jpg)

Comment: Assuming you have enabled a Web project in Firebase as you are able to login. Do you have added / enabled an Android project in the Firebase Console, too?

Comment: right, sdk setup , google-services.json, sha1 fingerprint. i did all and rules all read and right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Dabble every firebase android thing is enabled

Comment: yes every thing is enabled . someone said you need to open fire base in chrome for app firebase to happen